# PDO PHP Postgres: slow fetching of data

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, fetch

i was playing with PDO on PostgreSQL 9.2.4 and was trying to fetch data from a table having millions on rows. My query returns about 100.000 rows.
I do not use any of PDOStatements's fetch function, i simply use the result from the PDO Objecte itels and loop through it.
But its getting slower and slower by time. At the beginning it was fetching like 200 rows per second. But the close it comes to its end, it gets slower. Now being at row 30.000 it fetches only 1 row per second. Why is it getting slower.

I do this, its pretty simple:

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql...");
$sql = "SELECT x, y FROM point WHERE name is NOT NULL and place IN ('area1', 'area2')";
$res = $dbh->query($sql);
$ins_sql = "INSERT INTO mypoints (x, y) VALUES ";
$ins_vals = [];
$ins_placeholders = [];
foreach($res as $row) {
  $ins_placeholders[] = "(?,?)"; 
  $ins_vals = array_merge($ins_vals, [$row['x'], $row['y']]);
  printCounter();
}

// now build up one insert query using placeholders and values, 
// to insert all of them in one shot into table mypoints
```

Function printCounter simply increases an int var and prints it. So i can see how many rows it has put already in that array before i create my insert statement out of it. I use one shot inserts to speed things up, better than doing 100.000 inserts.
But that foreach loop is getting slower by time. How can i increase the speed.
Is there a difference between fetch() and the simple loop method using the pdostatement in foreach?

when i start this php script, it takes like 5-10 seconds for the query. So this has nothing to do with how the table is setup and if i need indexes.
I have other tables returning 1 million rows, im not sure what is the best way to fetch them. I can raise PHP's memory_limit if needed, so the most important thing for me is SPEED.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: If speed is your main concern, don't use PDO but the native lib instead. It is at least 10% faster.

Comment: well i use PDO because after the fetch i do insert them and would like to use the auto quoting feature of PDO

Comment: By "quoting", you mean escaping ?

Comment: yes i mean that binding to the ? characters on pdostatement's execute call. otherwise i would need to use addslashes or something similar. is PDO really that slow compared to the native one?

Comment: Yes, and I would suggest you use a prepared query if you still want to perform thousands of inserts. This way your values will be automatically escaped and the query plan will not be re-evaluated every time by the database.

Comment: Why don't you use the same [] method for the $ins_vals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i generated a class where i set the sql and then put the values for each row with a method call. Whenever it reaches a specific limit, it starts a transaction, prepares the statement with as many placeholders as i have put values, then executes it with the array having all the values, then commit.
This seems to be fast enough, at least it doesnt get slower anymore.
For some reason its faster to add values in a flat structure as Daniel suggested. Thats enough for me.

Sometimes its good to have a function doing one step of insertion, because when the function returns, all the memory used in the function will be freed, so your memory usage stays low.

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely that the slowness is related to the database, because after the `$dbh->query()` call, the query is finished and the resulting rows are all in memory (they are not in PHP variables yet, but they're in memory accessible at the pgsql module level).

The more likely culprit  is the `array_merge` operation. The array becomes larger at every loop iteration, and the operation recreates the entire array each time.

You may want to do instead:

```
$ins_vals[] = [$row['x'], $row['y']];
```

Although personally, when concerned with speed, I'd use an even simpler flat structure:

```
$ins_vals[] = $x;
$ins_vals[] = $y;
```

Another unrelated point is that it seems to build a query with a huge number of placeholders, which is not how placeholders are normally used. To send large numbers of values to the server, the efficient way is to use `COPY`, possibly into a temporary table followed by server-side merge operations if it's not a plain insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but using fetch() method instead and doing the $ins_val filling like this:

```
$ins_vals[] = $x;
$ins_vals[] = $y;
```

and using beginTransaction and commit makes now my script unbelievable fast.
Now it takes only about 1 minute to add my 100.000 points.

i think both array_merge and that "ugly" looping through the PDOStatement slowed down my script.

And why the heck someone downvoted my question? Are you punishing me because of my missing knowledge? Thanks.